# Can not run appium from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Appium -g is installed and I can run it from the terminal. But I can not do it from Jenkins even after writing path in .bash_profile. Just have a response: /var/folders/hg/prrxfjjj2cd_7jlzdwkqnrtc0000gn/T/jenkins953029489119055833.sh: line 2: appium: command not found Does anybody have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins doesn't run a bash login shell when shelling out to commands, so it won't read `~jenkins/.bash_profile`.  Instead try putting the full path to appium in your job configuration.  If you can't do that for whatever reason, try creating `/usr/local/bin/appium` or `/usr/bin/appium` as a symlink to your appium executable.